# Error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xsl:stylesheet'

Tags: xml, xslt

currently I am working with soap configuration and to do so, I am using an xsl file. But, when I tried to test the configuration, I got above error.

Here is the full error log:

[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]

And here is the content of my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
        <soapenv:Envelope >
            <soapenv:Header>
              <wsa:To>esbp://mycompany.de/lsmh/zks-eap</wsa:To>
              <wsa:MessageID>
                <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
              </wsa:MessageID>
              <wsa:Action>http://mycompany.de/zks-eap/<xsl:value-of select="//events/dataEvent[@name='request']/@value"/>
              </wsa:Action>
              <wsa:ReplyTo>
                <wsa:Address>esbp://mycompany.de/lsmh/mobako</wsa:Address>
              </wsa:ReplyTo>
              <wsa:From>
                <wsa:Address>esbp://mycompany.de/lsmh/mobako</wsa:Address>
              </wsa:From>
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <xsl:processing-instruction name="archimoaXsltConnector">callback="true"</xsl:processing-instruction>
                <zkseap:uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest xmlns:zkseap="http://mycompany.de/zks-eap">
                  <ausweis>
                    <nummer>
                      <xsl:value-of select="/ausweisnummer"/>
                    </nummer>
                  </ausweis>
                </zkseap:uebermittleAusweisdatenRequest>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Why am I getting those error? And how can I solve it? Thanks in advance.